# File not found localhost/phpmyadmin macos sierra 10.12.15

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, apache2, macos-sierra

i have a problem with phpmyadmin installation via brew, i have modified my root directory to point to /Users/username/Sites in /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf.

I have put this in the same file :

```
Alias /phpmyadmin #{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/share/phpmyadmin
      <Directory #{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/share/phpmyadmin/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
          Require all granted
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
        </IfModule>
      </Directory>
```

I use virtual host, so i create a symlink of the folder /usr/shar/phpmyadmin in /Users/username/Sites and create a phpmyadmin.conf like this:

```
<Directory "/Users/amerej/Sites/phpmyadmin">
    Allow From All
    AllowOverride All
    Options +Indexes
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:*>
    ServerName phpmyadmin.localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Users/amerej/Sites/phpmyadmin"
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9071/Users/amerej/Sites/phpmyadmin/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

I user follow this tutorial for using multiple versions of php :
https://lukearmstrong.github.io/2016/12/setup-apache-mysql-php-homebrew-macos-sierra/

Thank you if can help me i try to solve my problem alone but don't find the solution.

Comment: You should probably ask this over at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/